# What causes the TEST DRAFT button to suddenly become grayed out?

Tags: actions-on-google

All of a sudden the "TEST DRAFT" button is grayed out. Project was working fine, then suddenly I was unable to test on Google Home device, then noticed the "TEST DRAFT" button is grayed out. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any issues in your console metadata, such as missing an image or giving it a name that is not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. It appears that one's app is only testable for seven days after which one needs to recreate the app. See:

https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/simulator

Comment: Just to be clear, at least in the Actions SDK case "recreating" the app involves no more than uploading the action package using the gactions update command or maybe the update and test commands. I have one published action and one test action that share the same code base. When I get to a stable place testing locally, I push the code to my published action's host (GAE btw) and submit the action for review. I have been doing that for more than two going on three months.